# How can I use a graphic object's clear function(which requires a color argument) to clear the graphics of a form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

How can I use a graphic object's clear function(which requires a color argument) to clear the graphics of a form?

Using WFA

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Graphics gr;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gr = this.CreateGraphics();
            gr.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), 0, 0, 500, 500);
            //gr.Clear(); // ERROR IT NEEDS AN ARGUMENT BUT WHAT?
        }


    }
}
```

gr.Clear() needs an argument, but what colour?

I tried `MessageBox.Show(this.BackColor.ToString());`  so as to see the color of the form. But it just displays `"Color [Control]"` which doesn't tell me anything.

I tried `gr.Clear(Color.Gray)`   but that's not the correct colour, it's not the color of the default background of the form.

Comment: Why do you need to see the BackColor? Tried to just put this.BackColor into it? Or Color.Transparent if the control supports/needs transparency.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen   There is no Color.BackColor, but `gr.Clear(this.BackColor);` does it. You can post that as an answer.   BTW Color.Transparent doesn't do it

Comment: Fixed my typo. Transparent only works if your control is set to support transparency specifically, otherwise it won't.

Comment: and btw gr.Clear(BackColor)  is gr.Clear(this.BackColor) and "this" is the  form(and that's what we want), this is not the button.  Note- The button is passed to the button procedure though we aren't using it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating the control, I assume you should know what the color is. If you want the default control background color, just use `gr.Clear(BackColor)` There is no need to see what color it is, it just is the color you assigned to it or the system default.

For transparent controls you would use Color.Transparent, but usually controls are not needed to be transparent.